# Why exist two kinds of definition for formal proof?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, formal-proofs

There are two kinds of definition for formal proof in the logic books I read.

One is:
Let  be an ℒ-formula and  be an ℒ-theory. A formal proof
of  in  is a finite sequence of ℒ-formulas (0, ... , ) with 
equal to  such that, for every  ≤ , either  ∈ , or  is a
logical axiom, or it can be deduced by (MP) from some  and
 with ,  < , or it can be obtained by generalization from a
formula  with  <

The other is like this:
A formal proof is a sequence of $\sum_1\vdash A_1$,...,$\sum_n\vdash A_n$ where $\sum_i\vdash A_i$ is a rule itself or generated by previous ones using some rule(you can find the rules in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142517/formal-proof-propositional-logic)).

I did not see a proof like the second definition in other math books except some logic books. Why does the second kind of definition exist? Is there a systematic way (algorithm) to convert one kind of formal proof to the other?(I can convert simple proofs manually, but it seems hard to do so for complex proofs.)

Comment: Two different styles of logical calculus: Hilbert-style where derivations are sequences vs Natural Deduction and Sequent Calculus, where derivations are trees.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, but did you see a real proof that writes the premises before $\vdash$ in every step?